# Case insensitive text search in C#: How can I keep the original case when highlighting matching phrases?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a case insensitive text search (in the controller, I'm doing `.ToLower()` on both sides of the comparison), and I am highlighting the search phrases in the result text like this:

```
@Html.Raw(searchPhrase.Length == 0 
    ? item.Description 
    : (item.Description ?? "") // An item's Description could be NULL
        .Replace(searchPhrase, $"<span class='highlight'>{searchPhrase}</span>"))
```

Items matching the search phrase are displayed, but if the case doesn't match, there won't be any highlighting.

I want matching text to be highlighted even if the case doesn't match, and I want to keep the original case.

E.g.: If I search for "Potato", both "Potato" and "potato" should be highlighted in the search result.

I have seen some similar questions around, but not for C#, and I have not been able to translate any of the solutions to C#.

Comment: Well, `string.Replace` doesn't have an overload thet allows a case-sensitive comparision, but [`regex.Replace` does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_). What do you want to do with substrings, though? Should `potatomasher` be hightlighted when searching for 'potato'?

Comment: Could you do:  `item.description.Equals("What you're comparing against", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`  ?

Comment: @stuartd I only want the search phrase to be highlighted.

Comment: @Remy I'm not sure where the highlighting fits in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @stuartd 's comment, here is how to use `Regex.Replace` for the same thing:

```
var ans = searchPhrase.Length == 0
            ? (item.Description ?? String.Empty)
            : Regex.Replace((item.Description ?? String.Empty), // An item's Description could be NULL
                            Regex.Escape(searchPhrase),
                            "<span class='highlight'>$&</span>",
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can't do Replace like that because you are overwriting your source data.

You either need to mark the beginning and end of each match and, starting at the end of the string and going to the beginning, insert your opening and closing brackets, or write a custom replace routine.  I threw together a rather basic version of the latter, but it works.  It keeps the existing values so all cases will be preserved.

```
        string testData = "This is my fake data for matching this string";
        string searchPhrase = "thiS";
        string resultSet = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < testData.Length - searchPhrase.Length; i++)
        {
            if (searchPhrase.ToLower() == testData.Substring(i, searchPhrase.Length).ToLower())
            {
                resultSet += "<span class='highlight'>" + testData.Substring(i, searchPhrase.Length) + "</span>";
                i += searchPhrase.Length -1;
            }
            else
            {
                resultSet += testData[i].ToString();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(resultSet);
```

Granted, this code could probably be made faster with string parsing but I'll leave all that to you if you want to redo it.

Comment: For large amounts of text you'd want to use a StringBuilder for this.

Comment: @stuartd What is considered a large text? My `Description` fields are probably not going to be more than 1000 characters.

Comment: I wouldn't say that was large, no. But I would personally use a StringBuilder here.

Comment: that's a perfectly fine option but the project we use at work doesn't use stringbuilder in it so i'm not familiar enough with it to just throw together code that works so i fell back to simpler code.  I don't think it would be an improvement over a standard append though.  You are welcome to post code.  I'd like to see it myself.

Comment: To use a StringBuilder you would just have to change a couple of lines - declare it as `var resultSet = new StringBuilder();`, change the `resultSet +=` to `resultSet.Append` and when you want to result, `resultSet.ToString()`

Comment: And the reason to use this is - say in your code you called `resultSet +=` a million times. You've just allocated a million objects - as strings are immutable - which are each going to get progressively larger as text is appended. This _could_ lead to memory pressure or GC pauses - so my rule of thumb is -  if you are 100% sure you will only ever do up to a dozen or so string appends, then who cares how you do it. More than that, use an efficient method - [this article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) discusses it well.

Comment: @JohnLord There is a bug in your code. It clips off one character after the last matching character of the search phrase. If I have the text "keyboard" and searches for "key", the result is "[key]oard" ([] indicating highlighting)

Comment: good catch.  I incremented by the length of the search phrase and the loop incremented the i again.  Fixed now.  I do hope you were able to determine the problem on your own though as this code is pretty basic.  I just didn't test it thoroughly.